# Why does a matrix with zero eigenvalues and nonzero singular values have to be non-symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on some linear algebra prerequisites for Machine Learning algorithms.

I have found that a possible $n \times n$ matrix that has all its eigenvalues equal to zero but also has nonzero singular values has to be strictly upper or lower triangular.

However I am asked to explain why I **cannot** construct such an example that is also **symmetric** and I have to admit I am drawing a blank.

Comment: Not sure I udnerstand you but a strictly triangualar and symmetric matrix must be the $0$ matrix.

Comment: It doesn't have to be triangular. Consider, e.g. $\pmatrix{1&-1\\ 1&-1}$.

Comment: I thought that the relationship between eigenvalues and singular values is $\lambda = \sigma^2$ .  Hence, how is it possible for an eigenvalue to be zero and a singular value to be nonzero?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if a matrix is both symmetric and triangular then it is diagonal. We also know the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

A symmetric matrix is diagonalizable, and the only diagonalizable matrix with all eigenvalues zero is the zero matrix. Clearly the singular values of the zero matrix are all zero as well.